# How to start all tunnels defined in ngrok.yaml PyNgrok

Tags: ngrok, pyngrok

I have a custom config here is the sample:

```
log_level: info
region: ap
tunnels:
  http:
    addr: 5000
    proto: http
  ssh:
    addr: 22
    proto: tcp
```

I specify the config path on pyngrok but when I try to run ngrok.connect() only HTTP part is working and show on my ngrok dashboard, no ssh tunnel. When I try the ngrok binary provided by pyngrok:

```
ngrok start --all --config=/ngrok.yaml
```

It works! On my ngrok dashboard I have HTTP, HTTPS and TCP.

Answer (score 0):

These commands do not map to each other, which is why they do not do the same thing. [`connect()`](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.connect) calls `ngrok start --none`, so it starts the `ngrok` process and API with *no* tunnels running, then it starts a tunnel using the API with the params you've passed to `connect()`. To start multiple tunnels, just call `connect()` more than once with different params.

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

conf.get_default().region = "ap"

tunnel1 = ngrok.connect(addr=5000)
tunnel2 = ngrok.connect(addr=22, proto="tcp")
```

In the above example, the config file isn't even necessary. If you already have tunnel definitions in your config though, you can use them by just passing their name.

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

conf.get_default().config_path = "/ngrok.yml"


tunnel1 = ngrok.connect(name="http")
tunnel1 = ngrok.connect(name="tcp")
```

The docs, which have many examples of this and other usage, can be found [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe is not the solution but this worked for me

```
tunnels:
  http:
    addr: 5000
    proto: http
  ssh:
    addr: 22
    proto: tcp
```

`ngrok start http ssh`